# MFC control elements missing from the resource editor

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have a new Win32 application I'm starting in C++ with MFC.

It's my understanding that I should be able to use the resource view to edit the GUI elements of the application and add new controls.  When I try to add a new resource, however, I'm presented with a list that includes toolbar, bitmap, and a few other options but seems to be missing the most basic and most common Windows elements.

For example, where is the edit box, label, scroll viewer, stack panel, combo box, and button?

[image]

Am I going about this incorrectly, and if so, how do I add these basic elements to the view?

Comment: You add those (or most of them anyway, some I don't recognise from your descriptions) to a Dialog.  Once you have created a dialog, you'll find them in the Toolbox (under Dialog Editor).

Comment: That dialog allows you to add [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/introduction-to-resources) to a PE image. You can add a dialog resource, switch to the Resource View, and drag controls from the Toolbox onto it. If things work as designed, which they usually don't. Best to just get over it and introduce yourself to editing [resource files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files) manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was my intention to add UI and control elements to the main window, I didn't want to be restricted to using only popup dialogs.  To me that seems like an odd design decision and not how most modern applications work.

When creating a new MFC project, I found out we can select "Dialog Based" for Application Type instead of Single Document / Multiple Documents, and I created a new project with that selection.

In addition, I found out Visual Studio doesn't display the Toolbox by default (at least not for me).  I had to go to View->Toolbox before it would show up, even while in resource view.

Comment: The Toolbox toolwindow only automatically displays when you are editing something like a dialog resource or using some other designer (winforms for example) where it's actually useful.

If you want to just have a simple MFC app with a "main window" you would typically create an SDI based application with the view class derived from a CFormView. The CFormView uses a dialog resource. Edit the dialog resource, and you should see the toolbox with the various Win32 controls you can drag/drop onto the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, you can add edit box, label by adding a dialog resource and dragging from toolbox.
But in MFC application type SDI/MDI, you need to add controls by coding.

E.g. [CEdit::Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=msvc-170#create)